How to set-up medians lines over a geom_bar()?
I'm working on a plot that displays y values based on x categories and the medians associated. Here's the code:
Plot_RM <- ggplot(test_data) +
  aes(EX_ABS, RM_ABS)+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  geom_text(aes(label = RM_ABS), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.75))+
  geom_point(aes(x = EX_ABS, y = RM_MED), shape = "\u1397",color = "red")+
  labs(title = "Rapport des 1 RMs absolus (kg)",
       y = "RM (kg)",
       x = "Exercices")+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45,
                                   vjust = 1,
                                   hjust = 1, 
                                   size = 8),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 20),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 8),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 8),
        text = element_text(family = "copperlight"))

The goal is to add a "line" representing each X category's medians.
Here's my dataset:
dput(test_data)
structure(list(Masse = c(125.6, 125.6, 125.6, 125.6, 125.6, 125.6, 
125.6, 125.6, 125.6, 125.6, 125.6), Nom = c("Tikoipau", "Tikoipau", 
"Tikoipau", "Tikoipau", "Tikoipau", "Tikoipau", "Tikoipau", "Tikoipau", 
"Tikoipau", "Tikoipau", "Tikoipau"), Postes = c("PILIER", "PILIER", 
"PILIER", "PILIER", "PILIER", "PILIER", "PILIER", "PILIER", "PILIER", 
"PILIER", "PILIER"), EX_ABS = structure(1:11, levels = c("DC", 
"DM", "Trac", "Dips", "SQT", "FSQT", "SDT", "EPAU", "PP", "JETE", 
"ARRAC", "DIST_MAX_ABS"), class = "factor"), RM_ABS = c(145, 
NA, 266, NA, 204, NA, NA, 134, 125, NA, NA), RM_REL = c(1.15, 
NA, 2.11, NA, 1.62, NA, NA, 1.07, 1, NA, NA), RM_MED = c(145, 
80, 266, 118, 172, NA, 190, 109, 114, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

I tried to set up this with a geom_hline but the lines cross the entire plot. I prefer to use a geom_point with a different shape such as a "line" shape corresponding to "\u1397". However, when I print my plot I've got a little crossed rectangle which, I supposed, is similar to "NA" but for plots.
However, when running "\u1397" into my console it works.I don't understand the issue, may someone help me?

Here's a solution based on replacing your geom_point with geom_segment.  The calculation for the length of the line segments comes from the documentation for geom_bar, specifically the description of the width parameter.  If you don't want full-width lines, adjust accordingly.
w2 <- (resolution(as.integer(test_data$EX_ABS)) * 0.9) / 2

ggplot(test_data) +
  aes(EX_ABS, RM_ABS)+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  geom_text(aes(label = RM_ABS), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.75))+
  geom_segment(
    aes(
      x = as.integer(EX_ABS) - w2, 
      y = RM_MED, 
      xend = as.integer(EX_ABS) + w2), 
      color = "red"
    )
  ) +
  labs(title = "Rapport des 1 RMs absolus (kg)",
       y = "RM (kg)",
       x = "Exercices")+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45,
                                   vjust = 1,
                                   hjust = 1, 
                                   size = 8),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 20),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 8),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 8),
        text = element_text(family = "copperlight"))

Giving

I'm not sure your medians are correct! :-(

First of all realize that there are problems with the data,

column RM_ABS and its medians RM_MED have the same values in two rows;
Sometimes RM_ABS is NA but not RM_MED.

subset(test_data, RM_ABS == RM_MED)
#>   Masse      Nom Postes EX_ABS RM_ABS RM_REL RM_MED
#> 1 125.6 Tikoipau PILIER     DC    145   1.15    145
#> 3 125.6 Tikoipau PILIER   Trac    266   2.11    266
subset(test_data, is.na(RM_ABS) & !is.na(RM_MED))
#>   Masse      Nom Postes EX_ABS RM_ABS RM_REL RM_MED
#> 2 125.6 Tikoipau PILIER     DM     NA     NA     80
#> 4 125.6 Tikoipau PILIER   Dips     NA     NA    118
#> 7 125.6 Tikoipau PILIER    SDT     NA     NA    190

Created on 2024-08-19 with reprex v2.1.0

As for the plot's main problem, use geom_text instead of geom_point, like answered here.
I also define a custom theme, to make the code that follows lighter.
library(ggplot2)

theme_so_q78887391 <- function(){
  theme_minimal(base_size = 10) %+replace%    #
    theme(
      panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
      panel.grid = element_blank(),
      legend.position = "bottom",
      axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45,
                                 vjust = 1,
                                 hjust = 1, 
                                 size = 8),
      plot.title = element_text(size = 20),
      axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8),
      axis.title.x = element_text(size = 8),
      axis.title.y = element_text(size = 8)
      # , text = element_text(family = "copperlight")
    )
}


ggplot(test_data) +
  aes(EX_ABS, RM_ABS) +
  # geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_col(fill = "lightgrey") +
  geom_text(aes(x = EX_ABS, y = RM_MED), label = "\u1397", size = 15, color = "red")+
  geom_text(aes(label = RM_ABS), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.75)) +
  labs(title = "Rapport des 1 RMs absolus (kg)",
       y = "RM (kg)",
       x = "Exercices") +
  theme_so_q78887391()
#> Warning: Removed 6 rows containing missing values or values outside the scale range
#> (`geom_col()`).
#> Warning: Removed 3 rows containing missing values or values outside the scale range
#> (`geom_text()`).
#> Warning: Removed 6 rows containing missing values or values outside the scale range
#> (`geom_text()`).


Created on 2024-08-19 with reprex v2.1.0
